# Django Cannot Authenticate in the Login Page(Cant get in "user is not None")

Tags: django, django-forms

I did all the things according to the django.documentation, users are saved in database but still cannot log in homepage.  Always bringing back to me that 'Bilgilerinizi Kontrol Ediniz' error message. Could someone please about what can be the reason?

Here is my "**urls.py main**":

```
urlpatterns = [
path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
path('login', views.login_user, name='login'),
path('', views.homepage, name='home')
]
```

Here "**views.py**":

```py
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Bilgilerinizi Kontrol Ediniz')
            return redirect('login')
        
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

And here it is my "**login.html**" page:

```
<form action="" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="login-form">
                                <div>                            
                                    {% for message in messages %}
                                    <strong style="font-size: 0.8em;color:red">{{message}}</strong>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input class="input email-input" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail Adresiniz">
                                        <div class="input-icon">
                                            <i data-feather="user"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input class="input password-input" name="password" type="password" placeholder="●●●●●●●">
                                        <div class="input-icon">
                                            <i data-feather="lock"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field is-flex" style="margin-top: 12px">
                                <div class="switch-block" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                                        <label class="f-switch">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="is-switch">
                                            <i></i>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="meta">
                                            <p style="font-size:.8rem">Beni Hatırla</p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                    <a href="forget-password" style="margin-left: auto;font-size:.8rem;align-self: center">Şifremi Unuttum</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <button type="submit" class="button is-solid primary-button raised is-rounded is-fullwidth">Giriş Yap</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

And here is my database looks like:

[image]

Here it is how i save the passwords of users:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #acc_type = request.POST['acc_type']
    firstname = request.POST['firstname']
    lastname = request.POST['lastname']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    passwordconf = request.POST['password-confirmation']
    if password == passwordconf:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request, "Adınıza Kayıtlı Email Bulunmaktadır.")
            return redirect('signup')
        else:
            #saving user to database
            user = User.objects.create(username=firstname+' '+lastname, email=email, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, password=password )
            user.save()

            #creating profile object for the new user
            user_model = User.objects.get(username=firstname+' '+lastname)
            new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user_model, id_user=user_model.id)
            new_profile.save()
            return redirect('login')
            
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Şifreleriniz Eşleşmiyor.')
        return redirect('signup')
else:
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: Did you try printing the user? is it returning None? Can you also try without passing the request to the authenticate function?

Comment: Yes, i did, returned None. Deleted in the request paramater and tried too, but still same problem. returns always "None".

Comment: Can you translate "Bilgilerinizi Kontrol Ediniz"?

Comment: It means: "Check Your Informations". I also added database's screenshot.

Comment: Can you show how you are saving the passwords of users?

Comment: you have to mention login url in Form action i guess.

Comment: [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) takes `username` & `password` with `request` object but you've passed `email` instead of `username` change it to `username=email` it will work

Comment: If you've overridden your authentication backend then provide that too.